# Using imshow methods in a for loop to print multiple images

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, opencv

I have a simple 2d numpy array which is a pixel map of a gray scale image. I am trying to print some parts of the image. My code is

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/sample2.jpg') # the source file is correctly mounted
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

And

```py
i = 0
while i < (len(roi) - 1): # roi is a list of strictly increasing positive integers 
  print(roi[i], roi[i+1])
  plt.imshow(img_gray[roi[i]:roi[i+1]], cmap='gray')
  i += 1
```

For example if `roi = [10, 40, 50, 100]`, it should prints two parts of the image. But as I run the cell above, it only print one image which is the last part of the image. Is it possible not to overwrite other image and print them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try calling `plt.show()` after each `plt.imshow(...)`:

```py
i = 0
while i < (len(roi) - 1): # roi is a list of strictly increasing positive integers 
  print(roi[i], roi[i+1])
  plt.imshow(img_gray[roi[i]:roi[i+1]], cmap='gray')
  plt.show() # <----- this will show all plots
  i += 1
```

Or, if you want to keep a nicer, more organized plot, you could use subplots, although you should state how many subplots you want, here is an example with random input:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ims = np.random.randn(3, 224, 224)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].imshow(ims[i])
```

This last example will plot the images arranged horizontally:

[image: subplots example]